# attachEvent when DOM is loaded

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm setting an ID on `windows.onload` to a `button` element. Now I need to attach `onclick` on that button, but the **ID is undefined** at that moment.
How is the proper do this? I tried to attach the event like in the code below, or with `attachEvent`, and some other attempts with `onreadystatechange` or `DOMContentLoaded`. It`s a legacy appliaction in IE8, no libraries.
Thx!

```
window.onload = function () {

  var table = window.document.getElementById("TABLE");
  var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  table.appendChild(button);
  button.id = "BUTTON_ID"; // give id attribute after append to table 
  var row = TABLE.tBodies[0].rows;
  for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
    //...
  }
}

function BUTTON_ID.onclick() {

  //...
}
```

Comment: Is this really `jquery` question? `jquery.js` included?

Comment: No, I updated the tags. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach the event when the button is created:

```
window.onload = function () {

  [ ... ]

  var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  button.id = "BUTTON_ID";
  button.onclick = function() {
    alert("Clicked");
  }

  table.appendChild(button);

  [ ... ]
}
```

[JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4qnbpk6n/)